# What is the meaning of 「れど」 in the waka poem title 「忍ぶれど」?

Tags: translation, verbs, conjugations, classical-japanese, conjunctions

「忍ぶれど」 is the title of *Taira no Kanemori*'s *waka* poem in *Ogura Hyakunin Isshu* and I'd like to know the translation of this title in English.

I already looked up the meanings and

**「忍ぶ」** means

1. to conceal oneself; to hide
2. to endure

But I can't find the meaning of 「れど」

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Literally 忍ぶれど would translate to something like "even though I hide/conceal it". Here

- 忍ぶれ【しのぶれ】 is the [已然形](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B7%B2%E7%84%B6%E5%BD%A2) of the [上二段活用](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) verb 忍ぶ.
- ど is a conjunctive particle indicating contrast

  > #### ど
  >
  > （接助）
  >
  > 活用語の已然形に接続する。
  >
  > ① 逆接の確定条件を表す。実際に起こった事柄を条件としてあげ、その条件のもとでは、反対の結果が現れることを表す。が。けれども。 「子は京に宮づかへしければ、まうづとしけれ－、しばしばえまうでず／伊勢 84」 「格子をあげたりけれ－、守、心なしとむつかりて、おろしつれば／源氏 帚木」
  >
  > ② 一定の条件を示して、その条件のもとでは、それと背反関係にある事態がいつも起こることを表す。たとえ…たとしても。 「二人行け－行き過ぎかたき秋山をいかにか君がひとり越ゆらむ／万葉集 106」 「いにしへの古体の鏡は…人てふれね－、かくぞあかき／大鏡 後一条」 〔現代語では、「といえど」「と思えど」など、限られた言い方の中でしか用いられない。「暑いといえ－、我慢できないことはない」「言うまいと思え－今日の暑さかな」〕
  >
  > <sup>大辞林 via [kotobank.jp](https://kotobank.jp/)</sup>